# Trim Array Path TO JUST Filename

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsarray, tableview, uisearchbar

My NSArray is:

```
self.files  = [bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"ppt" inDirectory:@"thepowerpoints"];
```

This returns the full path of

```
/User/Name/.../filename.ppt
```

I can use a NSString to get only the filename using:

```
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [self.files objectAtIndex:thepath.row];
self.filenames = [[documentsDirectoryPath lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

Is there a way that I can cleanup the original NSArray to only return the lastPathComponent without the extension?

Am needing to do this to search within the tableview array.  Currently, if a file is named "Test.ppt" the search bar will show it if I type in "/User/Name", because the Array it is searching includes the entire path.

I would prefer for it to only search the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.files count]];
for (NSString *path in self.files) {
    [names addObject:[[path lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
}
self.files = names;
```

Comment: Well, that works to take care of the problem, but it created a new one.  When I set up the array like that, it can't load the .ppt into the webview, because the path is no longer part of the array.